# Eigen Value in Python

Tags: python, matlab, eigenvector

I wanted to find the Eigen value of a matrix size (280*280). I done it in MATLAB by using

```
[V D] = eig(matrix);
```

but I wanted to convert my code in python by using

```
d, v = np.eigh(matrix)
```

It will provide almost same output but in python the first and the last column are of opposite sign (i.e if positive in MATLAB then negative in python) and I know that MATLAB output is correct

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is equivalent only if your matrix is [hermitian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_matrix).

you should use in python:

```
d, v = np.eig(matrix)
```

A simple test you can do to make sure that what you compute is ok is to check that your eigenvalues and eigenvectors are correct by using :

```
d, v = np.linalg.eig(matrix)
norm_1=np.max(np.max(abs(np.matmul(np.matmul(v,np.diag(d)),np.linalg.inv(v))-matrix)))
print norm_1
```

the result of `np.max(np.sum(abs(np.matmul(np.matmul(v,np.diag(d)),np.linalg.inv(v))-matrix)))` is a simple case of a [Matrix norms induced by vector norms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm).

If your computation is ok the result should be around machine rounding error.